# TX PIO feature from Solarflare network card

Tags: network-adapter

I experimenting the Solarflare NIC feature called TX PIO. my understand is PIO transport data through CPU, DMA bypassed CPU by direct communication between devices. What is the different between the tranditional PIO, and Solarflare's TX PIO?

> PIO (programmed input/output) describes the process whereby data is
>   directly transferred by the CPU to or from an I/O device. It is an
>   alternative to bus master DMA techniques where data are transferred
>   without CPU involvement. **Solarflare 7000 series adapters support TX
>   PIO, where packet s on the transmit path can be “pushed” to the
>   adapter directly by the CPU.** This improves the latency of
>   transmitted packets but can cause a very small increase in CPU
>   utilisation. TX PIO is therefore especially useful for smaller
>   packets.

Comment: Your questions answers itself. TX is Transmit. So TX PIO is transmit PIO and not receive (RX) PIO.

Comment: so what make it faster than the tranditional PIO, and DMA?